# How do I hide HTML for a specific Bootstrap tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm using Bootstrap tabs on one of my webpages, for a job application portal. The tab content for each `<li>` consists of a) a job title, b) a job description, and c) an "Apply Now" button. I need to hide the "Apply Now" button for one of my positions when it's clicked on, but have it show for the rest.

I've tried accomplishing this using an event handler in two different ways, but have been unsuccessful:

Accounting for the hash populated in the address bar for that tab:

```
$('.careers-positions li').on('click', 'a', function() {
  if (window.location.hash === '#it-consultant') {
    ('.tab-content .apply-button').addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    ('.tab-content .apply-button').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

The "Apply Now" button also has a data-jobid attribute, tied to a click event, that changes value based on the position that's clicked on in my list. But for some reason approaching it from this way has also been unsuccessful:

```
$('.careers-positions li').on('click', 'a', function() {
  if ($('.tab-content .apply-button').attr('data-jobid') === 'fd39f67d-8e99-476b-8421-080d8dca42e0') {
    $('.tab-content .apply-button').addClass('hidden');
  }
 });
```

How can I configure this so that the "Apply Now" button will dynamically show/hide based on whether this particular job title is clicked on?

Comment: can you put your html code?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```js
$('.careers-positions li a[data-jobid="fd39f67d-8e99-476b-8421-080d8dca42e0"]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.apply-button').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you have multiple tabs w/ multiple jobs in each tab??? And each "job" is using a `<ul>` structure?

You can use the `$(this)` and get the parent, rather than selected all the "tabs", as you've done when you use

```
$('.careers-positions').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.apply-button').hide();  // can you not just use this??? 
    // or instead of hide() use the .addClass('hidden'), either or
 });
```